# Python request input's id from a form

Tags: python, html, forms

I use google app engine and python. I want to retrieve the id of an input and not the value. If I use `self.request.get("thename")` I get the value of the input.

Here is the html

```
<form method="post">
   <input value=" " type="submit" name="thename" id="thenumberIneed"/>
</form>
```

I cannot put my data on the value tag because I have an image as a background on the input and if I enter there anything, the data shows infront of the image. So, I keep value empty.

Comment: The id isn't sent to the server, so you can't retrieve it.

Comment: any way to add a value without showing it on the page?

Comment: Fix the image problem, not this one.

Comment: can you put whatever you need in a hidden input inside the same form?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the value to show, change it to:

```
<input type="hidden" ... />
```

But I suspect there are other problems you should be solving, like why does your image get in the way of showing values in the page, and what kind of data you want to retrieve.

Comment: If I change the type to hidden, then I cannot use it as a button.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the id for this type of logic.

You would have better luck using a seperate hidden input field, for example.

```
<input type='hidden' name='myval' value='thenumberyouneed' />
```

And then you can just do your search for myval and get your answer.